# There is error c++ with gnuplot. The graph doesn't work

Tags: c++, gnuplot, gnuplot-iostream

```
#include "StdAfx.h"
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "pGNUPlotU.h"

int main(void)
{
    double N = 5;
    double w_c = 2;
    double w;
    CpGnuplotU plot (_T("C:\\Program Files\\gnuplot\\bin\\wgnuplot.exe"));

    FILE *fp = _wfopen (_T("C:\\temp\\1.dat"), _T("wt"));
    if (fp) {
        for (double w = 0; w < 2; w += 0.01) 
        {
            fwprintf(fp, _T("%f, %f, %f \n"), w, 1 / sqrt(1 + (1 * cos(N * acos(w / w_c)) * cos(N * 
acos(w / w_c)))));
        }
        for (double w = 2; w < 20; w += 0.01) 
        {
            fwprintf(fp, _T("%f, %f, %f \n"), w, 1 / sqrt(1 + (1 * cosh(N * acos(w / w_c)) * cosh(N * 
acos(w / w_c)))));
        }
        fclose (fp);
    }

    plot.cmd (_T("splot 'C:\\temp\\1.dat' with line"));

    getchar();
}
```

The fomula is about Chebyshev filter.
Is there anyone who used gnuplot in c++?
the first for statement(w=0; w<2; w+= 0.01) is normally work.
I can see the exact graph.
But the second for statement(w=2; w<2; w+= 0.01) isn't work.
There is nothing on my graph.

What is problem? How can I solve it?
I want your answer.
Thank You

Comment: You wrote `w < 20` in your code, but you wrote `w < 2` in your question, about the second `for` statement. Which is your actual code?

Answer (score 2):

You put three `%f`s in the format specifier, but you give only two data:

- `w`
- `1 / sqrt(1 + (1 * cosh(N * acos(w / w_c)) * cosh(N * acos(w / w_c))))`

to the `fwprintf`. This will invoke *undefined behavior*. You have to give enough number of data to print.